# How to have multiple language columns in a Resource file in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: visual-studio, user-interface, visual-studio-2022, resx, resourcemanager

I am on a new .Net project. I want to make localized text, using Visual Studio's Resource files.

I remember from a former job that they had a column for each language when editing the said files.

I tried to make two files, names UI.resx and UI.fr.resx, to try.

But when I open UI.resx, I only have the columns "Name", "Value" and "Commentary". The language isn't even precised on the column

[Screenshot of the editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gupi6.png)

[Screenshot of the file explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Myxeb.png)

What am I doing wrong ?

I've searched online, but I didn't find anything about this.

I don't know if they had an addon, I don't think they were, but if there is one, I'll gladly get it

Comment: While i believe it is possible to edit .resx file's structure (via customuzing XML and creating your own readers/writers for it), it's soo not worth the effort. I would suggest using something like [ResX Manager extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TomEnglert.ResXManager)

Comment: I was looking for something like that, thank you so much !